# Virtual Interface Not Showing up in ifconfig?

Tags: linux, centos, ethernet

I am trying to create a virtual interface for the purpose of NameBased Virtual Hosting on my CentOS linux box; please find below is the devices' information:-

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=00:0c:29:4e:1c:14
MTU=1500
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=yes
IPV6INIT=no


DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.1.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=no
HWADDR=00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
TYPE=Ethernet
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0:1"
UUID=7758ac79-c4a2-dd87-1760-71284a316d00
```

Running ifconfig doesn't show the virtual device eth0:1;

```
[root@centos network-scripts]# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:1c14/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9793531 (9.3 MiB)  TX bytes:4460526 (4.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:799 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:799 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:82196 (80.2 KiB)  TX bytes:82196 (80.2 KiB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr EE:75:AD:75:9C:84
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Any ideas what I might be missing.

----------Edit 1:-

Restarted my linux box and could see all the configured virtual interfaces as below:-
After System Restart:-

```
[root@centos ~]# date
Tue Apr 30 21:25:16 PDT 2013
[root@centos ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:1c14/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9756 (9.5 KiB)  TX bytes:17204 (16.8 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
          inet addr:192.168.1.40  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 b)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 b)
```

But after doing `system-network-restart` all my settings are gone: Please find below is the result after running the command:-

```
[root@centos ~]# service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
state: activated
Connection activated

[root@centos ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4e:1c14/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:25640 (25.0 KiB)  TX bytes:41720 (40.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 b)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

then that interface will Up when you start/restart network service 
Or you can manually Up that interface using

```
ifup eth0:1
```

for down

```
ifdown eth0:1
```

Comment: after restarting my linux box; I can see all the configured virtual interfaces but restarting the network only doesn't work. I have add ed sample in my question

Comment: are you using `/etc/init.d/network restart` or what ?

Comment: i am using service network restart

Comment: seems fine.. but also stop NetworkManager service from startup and also check `/var/log/messages` for any error

Answer (score 0):

The virtual interface (aka. alias device) needs to be in it's own separate file **ifcfg-eth0:1** like so:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0C:29:4E:1C:14
TYPE=Ethernet
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0:1"
UUID=7758ac79-c4a2-dd87-1760-71284a316d00
```

#### References

- [Adding Virtual Network Interfaces on CentOS 5.x](http://www.selbytech.com/2009/10/adding-virtual-network-interfaces-on-centos-5-x/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, but I did create the file.

Comment: change none to static.

Answer (score 0):

You must change `BOOTPROTO=none` to `BOOTPROTO=static`.

Comment: both means are same... means static

Comment: @RahulPatil Not according to the documentation. My man page (`ifcfg`) says: "For  bonding  slaves and bridge ports to skip the interface configuration." Hard to believe that this should have changed.

Comment: hmm good to know.. but have you tried.. they work the same..

Comment: @RahulPatil No, I haven't tried. But that is strange.

Comment: Actually `none` is one of the possible values for `BOOTPROTO`, not `static` according to the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0) (for RHEL5). Another way to check this would be to run `less /usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt` followed by a search for `BOOTPROTO`.